# Entity Framework and remote tables: mimic the raw SQL execution as done in SSMS

Tags: azure, entity-framework

I am still struggling with executing raw SQL on my remote tables when it comes to Entity Framework.

As the `dbcontext` is running inside the cloud, I am never able to execute raw SQL using Entity Framework.

I can however just log into SSMS (or any other db visualizer) and simply make SQL statements there.

How is this done under the hood?

Is this a rest call to a server?

How can I mimic this behavior coming from C# code base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried according to your requirement in my environment.
Firstly, I have created an Azure SQL server and database in portal.

[image]

Then I have configured the below code to communicate between the application with Azure database.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "give your connection string";

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                string query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Persons] (PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City)\r\nVALUES (3, 'Suresh', 'Babu', 'Stavanger', 'India');";

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("Row inserted successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Hardcoded the raw data that inserts into database.
`string query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Persons] (PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City)\r\nVALUES (3, 'Suresh', 'Babu', 'Stavanger', 'India');";`

Click on [packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK5ep.png)  to view which installed for the application.

Iam able to insert the row successfully.

[image]

Below is the output data after running the query.

[image]

Comment: thank you my friend. after many weeks of trying to find ways of how to join two tables together using entity framework i decvided i am just going to go the raw sql route. this really helped me out a lot!